# How to upload to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

1. How do I upload to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, not the Firebase Storage? According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference) , the way you get a reference to the Firebase storage and Cloud storage seem to be exactly the same.  But, when I try to access the bucket from Cloud Function, I am given two choices (`gcf-sources-234340858426-us-central1` and `us.artifacts.233093489-23.appspot.com`) that are completely different from the Firebase Storage (`gs://someaddress.appspot.com`). I'm currently able to upload to Firebase storage with the Firebase SDK from the front end.
2. Can Firebase Storage trigger Google Cloud Function with event triggers?

Comment: Firebase is an integrated platform for web services including a number of services designed to work together plus excellent mobile support. Google Cloud is a much larger platform designed to support the development of anything and everything. Firebase Storage and Cloud Storage are the same service. This article might help you understand: https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-storage-a33fad7c2b80

Comment: But, how do I upload files to Google Cloud Storage? When I initialize the Firebase account and download the iOS SDK, the uploaded files go to the Firebase Storage. I tried modifying GoogleService-Info.plist by changing the `STORAGE_BUCKET` to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, but I get only an error.

Comment: I cannot answer that part as I do not develop for mobile (Android/iOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Uploading Files

Cloud Storage buckets and Firebase buckets are the same thing under the hood. That said, if you want to use the Google Cloud-specific (i.e. non-Firebase) approach, you can use the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#rest-upload-objects) or the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample).

#### Triggering functions

Yes - you should be able to trigger a [Storage-triggered function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) by uploading files to a bucket. The deployment command might look something like this:

```
# Note: this is untested, and assumes you have the Google Cloud SDK installed
gcloud functions deploy my-function --trigger-bucket "someaddress.appspot.com"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: BTW, here's some instructions on how to install the Cloud SDK: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart